# Shell: Check if any file in directory has changed

Tags: shell

I'm using [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) in order to watch out if any file within a directory has been modified:

```
while inotifywait -e modify /etc/checking/; do
    curl...
done
```

Nevertheless, `modify` watches out that a watched file or a file within a watched directory **was written to**, regardless of whether the written content is the same.

Before sending a new `curl` I'd like to check if the previous watched out files content really has changed.

I was thinking about using `md5sum` commands to take advantadge of.

1. So, I'd need to save a `md5sum` output for each file into an array. Any ideas?
2. When `modify` event is trigered compare with previous `md5sum`s

**I'm using `#!/usr/bin/env sh`**

Any ideas?

Comment: `md5sum` outputs a list, save it to a file. Use `diff` to compare old and new.

Comment: It's not able to set a directory to `md5sum` as a parameter

Comment: You can send it a list of files: E.g `md5sum directory/*` (note, this ignores hidden files).

Comment: Upmod for the question from someone who just wanted to know how to watch for writes and needed to know `inotifywait` !

Answer (score 2):

You can checksum all files in a specific directory (`/etc/checking`) recursively and write the checksum code in a file. Then, when you want to search for modifications, simply compare it by running trough the list.

```
find /etc/checking -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > checklist.chk
```

checklist.chk will look like this:

```
bda7d4479b770eb055287d265b62c056  /etc/checklist/file001
83087902bc3bfea5cf8594c7d3f5c350  /etc/checklist/file002
7af7a423d53450e75fc228d6163ae9e6  /etc/checklist/file003
```

Then to compare it with the checklist:

```
md5sum -c checklist.chk
```

and it will output:

```
/etc/checklist/file001: OK
/etc/checklist/file002: OK
/etc/checklist/file003: OK
```

You can easily add this in a cronjob to run it every day for exemple.

---

You can also use the same command to output a new checklist at each time and run a [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) command between two checklists.

Answer (score 1):

I created [dir-fingerprint](https://github.com/nejckorasa/dir-fingerprint/) that can be used to solve that. It creates fingerprint/checksum for all the files in directory tree and saves it in a files, also telling you if the fingerprint has changed.

It can be installed with:

```
$ brew install nejckorasa/tap/dir-fingerprint
```

and used as:

```
$ dir-fingerprint <path_to_directory>
```

with output:

```
Old     [8a7b73f9671004edd50500bc7d3f1837d841a5c086011207259eb2d183823adf]
New     [8a7b73f9671004edd50500bc7d3f1837d841a5c086011207259eb2d183823adf]
@       <path_to_directory>/.fingerprint
Diff    false
```

and `.fingerprint` file created

Answer (score 0):

How about using a version control, like `git` in a loop? That monitors all changes and can output parse-able data with `git status --porcelain`, where you can see if it is a modification of data or new file and does not show if the content haven't really changed. Example:

```
$ git init
$ echo "aa" > file1
$ git add file1
$ git commit -m "initial"
$ echo "bb" > file2
$ echo "aa" > file1
$ git status --porcelain
```

outputs:

```
?? file2
```

The downside is, that `inotify` is closely connected to the real filesystem, while git is much more high level (and therefore has overhead).